# Facing an error : table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, ora-00942

I am using insert statement and trying to insert data into the database table. I am using stored procedures.

But I am getting this error while doing so.

> Message: ORA-00942: table or view does
>   not exist ORA-06512

I checked if the tables/stored procedures are present or not and everything is in place. Also there is no typo in table names or in sp. If I run the part of SP from query editor it works fine but when I execute the entire SP it throws an error.

I tried the steps provided by Stephen but since I have logged in with the same user/owner when I run Grant command it gives me an error saying 'Cannot Grant/revoke on own'.

One more addition to this. I have a stored procedure SP1 in which I am using a select statement as

```
Select a from table_name where condition;
```

When I execute this seperately, it returns me some results. But when I execute sp it gives an error at the same line where it is written.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue. I am using SQL +.

Thanks in advance
Vijay

Comment: Lots of possibilities: Connecting to the wrong database? Typo in the name of the table? You've got to give us more to go on here.

Comment: Can you show us your procedure or the insert statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Justin's answer is correct but let me expand a bit.

Everyone who said that the table doesn't exist didn't read your whole post. Since you are able to:

> If I run the part of SP from query editor it works fine

Obviously the table is there.
Obviously you have some access to it. Otherwise this wouldn't work when it clearly does.

> but when I execute the entire SP it throws an error.

This is because Oracle distinguishes between permissions granted directly and those granted via a role.

Say I do this:

```
Create Table TABLE_A
Create Role READ_ONLY
Grant Select on TABLE_A to READ_ONLY
Grant READ_ONLY to VIJAY
```

In a SQL Window/prompt you could query that table without issue. So now you need to create a view

```
Create VIJAY.VIEW_A as SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
```

You'll get the error that TABLE_A does exist. Because a view is compiled, like a procedure it runs without any roles. Since it runs without the READ_ONLY role, it's blind to the fact that TABLE_A exists. Now what I need to do is

```
Grant Select on TABLE_A to VIJAY.
```

Now that you have a direct permission, you can compile a view or procedure/package that uses that table.

Comment: Thanks for so detailed explanation. I tried the above steps but since I have logged in with the same user/owner when I run Grant command it gives me an error saying 'Cannot Grant/revoke on own'.

Comment: Wait, the procedure and table are owned and run by the same user? This makes no sense. A procedure in the same schema as the table doesn't NEED permissions to the table. Can you post the procedure code from CREATE to BEGIN?

Answer (score 8):

Does the table exist in the schema where the stored procedure exists?  If not, the simplest explanation is that the owner of your procedure has been granted access to the table via a role not via a direct grant.  A definer's rights stored procedure needs to have direct access to the objects it accesses.  A quick way to test this is to disable roles for the session, i.e.

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> <<execute your query>>
```

If that generates the error, the problem is the lack of a direct grant.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can choose if the stored procedure is executed with the rights of the invoker or the definer: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm#i18574

Check if the AUTHID property of the stored procedure is correct and if the resulting user has appropriate permissions.

Comment: While true, I doubt this user has changed the Authid. Justin's answer is more likely the case. The confusion over grants through a role and direct are compounded by the query working from a sql prompt but not compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Well, put very simply, the table that you are trying to insert data into does not exist in the database you are connected to.  You need to check both those things (i.e. what are you connected to, and is the table there and accessible for the user context you are using).

Comment: And also, check if the user/schema that you're using to connect to the database, has rights enought to see this table/view.

Comment: Not "rights enough to see". That can be done through a role. As Justin said, set role none and THEN test if you can access the table.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe Stefanelli said .. there are a lot of possibilities for the error being shown here.

Check whether:

1. You are connecting to the correct Oracle Instance.
2. You have permissions to query or perform processing on table that you are referencing in your query.
3. There is a difference between ordinary select statements and procedures. Procedures in oracle do not respect the roles assigned to a user; rather the permission needs to be explicitly granted to the user. For more information read the following link[ORA-00942](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/err/ora_00942.html)